# powershell script to find userprofile and change directory to the profile

Tags: powershell

I am making a script where I will output a report but when I run the script as administrator it changes the directory to C:\WINDOWS\system32.  What I am trying to accomplish is to $env:USERPROFILE then change to that directory.  This script will be used multiple times on different endpoints.  I am open to any suggestions of how to accomplish this or better commands to use.

```
            cd %userprofile%\desktop\
                            
            netsh interface show interface >%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            netsh interface ip show config >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            netstat -ano >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            netstat -r >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            netstat -b -v >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            netstat -s >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            nbtstat -R >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            ipconfig /flushdns >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            ipconfig /registerdns >>%userprofile%\desktop\nicreset.txt

            start notepad "nicreset.txt"
```

Comment: I am new at powershell and this will be part of a menu to be used by others for troublehooting windows updates, networking and various other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to be quite Batch-like. Let's make it powershell:

```
Set-Location "$($env:UserProfile)\Desktop"
netsh interface show interface >.\nicreset.txt
netsh interface ip show config >>.\nicreset.txt
netstat -ano >>.\nicreset.txt
netstat -r >>.\nicreset.txt
netstat -b -v >>.\nicreset.txt
netstat -s >>.\nicreset.txt
nbtstat -R >>.\nicreset.txt
ipconfig /flushdns >>.\nicreset.txt
ipconfig /registerdns >>.\nicreset.txt
notepad.exe ".\nicreset.txt"
```

Comment: this worked perfectly.  I am use to writing batch scripts so wanted to create a powershell script and modify it as I learn more.  There is so much to learn. Thank you for the answer.